# Methodology to forecast yearly data for various countries

Tags: regression, forecasting, methodology

I am looking for a suitable forecasting methodology based on the following data sets I have across countries.

Independent variables - I have data available for variables A,B, and C from 2010 to 2020 for UK,France, Germany, Spain and Italy.
Dependent variable - I have data available for variable D from 2010 to 2020 for UK,France and Germany only.

I would like to know a suitable methodology that I can use to predict the values of variable D for Spain and Italy from 2010 to 2020.

Thanks,
A.W

Comment: Welcome to CV! Your question has been flagged as off-topic. I struggle to understand why and have voted to leave it open, though you may find that others consider it too broad: Including more details may help you find a helpful answer.